# datetime-local php variable value

Tags: php

I'm trying to put a value for my datetime-local input in a form and nothing show. I'm taking my value from a php variable taken from a db. Here's my code:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $desc = substr($row['description'], 0, 200);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $nextrun = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['nextrun']));       

      <div class="modal fade" id="edit<?php echo $id;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">            
           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $nextrun; ?>" name="TaskNextRun" required>
           </div>
      </div>
```

I've simplify my code for you to see the essential
So when I open my update modal, nothing appears for the date input

[image: result]

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can't parse HTML in php like that ..

Comment: But I'm able to do it with other value and other input like a name, why not a date?